# Confirmation alert Before Delete record with jQuery AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is that when I press yes on delete confirmation the db record goes away,but if I refresh the page it comes back.

Maybe  I have to put the language and the id inside the Ajax URL ?

If yes how can I do this?

Please forgive me I am still learning.

[image]

This is my code from **delete_table.php**

PS: this is how the delete button is on the site for example: **delete_table.php?lang=en&id=149**

```
       if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
      {

       $id = $_GET['id'];


      if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `articles_".LANG."` WHERE id = 
      ? LIMIT 1"))
      {
     $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
      }
      else
      {
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
      }
```

This is the delete button from the **index.php**.

```
<td><a class='delete' id='del_".$row->id."' href='delete_table.php?lang=".LANG."&id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>
```

This is the **delete.js** where the jquery and ajax is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Delete 
$('.delete').click(function(event) {
    var el = this;
    var id = this.id;
    var splitid = id.split("_");

    // Delete id
    var deleteid = splitid[1];

    // Confirm box
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure want to delete this article?",
        function(result) {

            if (result) {
                // AJAX Request
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'delete_table.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id: deleteid },
                    success: function(response) {

                        // Removing row from HTML Table
                        $(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
                        $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
            console.log('delete_table.php');
        });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your query is not executing but it is being removed from your view with `$(this).remove();`

Answer (score 1):

this is what you are looking for

```js
function confirmDelete() {
    if (confirm("Delete Record?") == true) {
        alert("Now deleting");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Cancelled by user");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<td><a class='delete' id='del_".$row->id."' href='delete_table.php?lang=".LANG."&id=" . $row->id . "' onclick="return confirmDelete()">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: hm , but is this ajax ? I am trying to use this example from here http://makitweb.com/confirmation-alert-before-delete-record-with-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Confirm method does not accept function as second argument.
The confirm() method returns true if the user clicked "OK", and false otherwise. So Save this result in variable and based on that fire ajax or do nothing.

```
var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
if(result) {
    // fire ajax
}
```

Comment: I am using this example from here http://makitweb.com/confirmation-alert-before-delete-record-with-jquery-ajax/ , i can see that he is using POST ID and i have GET ID , what do you say ? thank you.

Comment: getting 404 on this link

Comment: hm wierd works if i click it [link](http://makitweb.com/confirmation-alert-before-delete-record-with-jquery-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

ADD if(response ==1) then remove row from HTML

```
                    // Removing row from HTML Table

                    $(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
                    $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
```